# What made “gusto” popular?

Tags: word-usage, etymology, italian

***[Gusto](https://www.etymonline.com/word/gusto#etymonline_v_14394)*** is a foreign term which the English language appears to have borrowed twice:

> 1620s, "***very common from the beginning of the 19th c." [OED]***, from Italian gusto "taste," from Latin gustus "a tasting," related to gustare "to taste, take a little of." .... English first borrowed the French form, guste "organ of taste; sense of taste" (mid-15c.), but this became obsolete. (Etymonline)

Though the term was actually used from early 1600s  only from [the beginning of 1800s](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=gusto&year_start=1770&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgusto%3B%2Cc0) its  usage became popular,  and given its main current meaning:

> great energy, enthusiasm, and enjoyment that is experienced by someone taking part in an activity, especially a performance. (Cambridge Dictionary)

I wonder if the term gained popularity with the Italian lyric [Opera](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opera) in England which at that time dominated the  musical   scene in theaters. If not, what may have increased the usage  of the term gusto?

Comment: It sounds so good when you say it with gusto!

Comment: Who can tell? What kind of evidence do you think would support your hypothesis or an alternative?

Comment: The OED doesn't support your contention. It shows gusto in the sense "Keen relish or enjoyment displayed in speech or action; zest." from the 17th century onwards, with a good example from Samuel Pepys "He read me, though with too much gusto, some little poems of his own." It's possible this sense became more popular in the 19th century, but I think that remains unproven.

Comment: This seems a bit POB the way that it's phrased.  Who can say how something gained popularity?  Unless there's a period piece discussing the mindset on it. I think it might be more utile to ask in what realm it gained traction which is sort of how I'm reading your question.  Or perhaps whether or not it was always present, but its meaning shifted over time.

Comment: @DavidM - the OED says “very popular from the beginning of the 19th century” and that appears to be confirmed by Google Books too, so something happened at that time with the term gusto. That’s what I am looking for and I am asking for evidence.  I don’t see an opinion based  issued here.

Comment: @user067531 I see your angle and withdraw my objection.  I like the question, though.  I had already upvoted it.

Comment: Why is "gusto" different from any Italian loanword?

Comment: Gelato has now been adopted in the English language, quite recently too. Why? Because people like Italian ice creams. Because Italy is famous for its cuisine. Because it's chic to say things in Italian and appear to be educated and knowledgeable at the same time. The same for "gusto" but here the pronunciation changes.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - “gusto”  is a much more specific word than pizza, cappuccino or gelato. You don’t buy, eat or sell “gusto”. It must have found its way into the English language somehow...how?

Comment: And the fact its pronunciation changes  is curious and interesting too. And that might lead to some interesting discovery. Well, might have...

Comment: Do you think only Italian food can be imported? What about art, music, science, and medicine? There is a plethora of Italian loanwords in those fields.

Comment: Why have Italians adopted "skill" and made it into a verb?! Because that's what happens to loanwords. https://www.leonardocalabresi.com/blog/skillato-o-skilled-cosa-significa-esattamente/

Comment: Ok, the answer is “that’s what happens to loanwords”..

Comment: @Mari-LouA - just one more thing...the meaning in English is not the main one “taste” but its extension “enthusiasm and enjoyment”. They actually imported only the expression “con gusto” that has the second connotation.

Comment: @Mari-LouA  Very interesting article. But, I think he's missing that skillato is a misunderstanding of the word skilled as if it's a past tense and is a misguided attempt to make a participle. Maybe he says that, my Italian is of the Rosetta Stone variety.

Comment: @user067531 Yes. I got that. I'm just wondering if the -ato is reverse engineered from -ed as the participle of a verb as Mari-Lou is suggesting. Sono skillato. A conjugation of skillare?  Or is it the adjective -ed in English. I'd have thought the latter, ML said verb in her introduction to the article.

Comment: @DavidM it is actually an adjective. In case you are interested: http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/lingua-italiana/parole-nuove/skillato

Comment: @user067531 I see. You guys are saying the verb was back formed from the adjective.

Comment: Note that _gusto_ is also a Spanish word and that English-Spanish interaction became increasingly common in the 1800s as the United Sates and Latin America came into closer contact. ¡Mucho gusto!

Comment: @SvenYargs - yes, but I couldn’t find evidence in that respect.

Comment: @SvenYargs I also wouldn't be surprised if *gusto* grew in popularity with immigration patterns to the US. I don't know how to prove a causal relationship though.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Cheers, old bean!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Was Gusto Popular?

The NGram data on *gusto* is borne out by both the [Corpus of Historical American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coha/) and the [Hansard (British parliamentary) Corpus](https://www.english-corpora.org/hansard/). For instance, here is the results for *gusto* in Hansard, divided by decade:

[image]

Note the first instance after 1850, the growth in usage around 1920, and its resurgence after 1980. Here is COHA:

[image]

So the corpus data, broadly speaking, agrees. This shows that gusto did become more popular in English, at least in the 1920s and 1930s, and we also know from the OED that it became more common in its current usage in the early 19th century. What caused either of these spikes?

---

### The Dictionary Explanation - Italian Loanwords

One explanation would place *gusto* in the same realm as other loanwords from Italian, French, and Spanish during the early modern period. *Gusto* was included in many early bilingual and trilingual lexicons prepared for people who may travel to Italy, trade with Italians, or read Italian literature. So, like some of these words, *gusto* may have come into English in a fairly literal meaning and changed from there.

In the search engine [Lexicons of Early Modern English](https://leme.library.utoronto.ca), gusto comes up 50 times between the *Medulla Grammatice (Pepys MS 2002)* (c. 1480) and Samuel Johnson's *Dictionary of the English Language* (1750). I've selected five samples that show the word in gradual transition from being a **translated Italian word meaning *taste*** to **a loanword in English meaning *excitement***:

> ***Gusto on*** | anglice a Taster // ***Gusto as*** | anglice to Taste ([MG, c. 1480](https://leme.library.utoronto.ca/lexicon/entry/537/6605))
>
> **Gusto, as.** to taste, to smacke: also to haue a little knowledge or experience in: to attaine to a meane. (Thomas Thomas, *[Dictionarium Linguae Latinae et Anglicanae](https://leme.library.utoronto.ca/lexicon/entry/179/15623)*, 1587)
>
> **Gust or Gusto**, a right Relish, Savour, or true Taste of any thing. A Delicious Gusto, Wines, Fruits, or Meats of a curious or pleasant Taste. A Gust of Wind, a short, sudden, furious Blast, as we say a Dash of Rain, for a sudden, short, impetuous Beat of Rain.(B. E., A New Dictionary of the Terms Ancient and Modern of the Canting Crew, 1699)
>
> **GU＇STO**, It. 1. A relish, favour, or taste of any thing, the power by which any thing excites sensations in the palate. Pleasant gusto＇s. Derham. 2. Intellectual taste or liking. Let them bring no particu­lar gusts along with them. Dryden. (Joseph Nicol Scott, *[A New Universal Etymological English Dictionary](https://leme.library.utoronto.ca/lexicon/entry/1346/33023)*, 1755)
>
> **GU’STO**. n. s. [Italian.] 1. The relish of any thing; the power by which any thing excites sensations in the palate. Pleasant gustos gratify the appetite of the luxurious. Derh. 2. Intellectual taste; liking. In reading what I have written, let them bring no particular gusto along with them. Dryden. (Samuel Johnson, *[A Dictionary of the English Language](https://leme.library.utoronto.ca/lexicon/entry/1345/17519)*, 1755)

So eighteenth century dictionaries pick up on *gusto* as an English word, and the meaning is expanding to include not just *taste* or even *intellectual preference* but a kind of pleasure or excitement derived from one of them. So later developments in English *gusto* would most likely occur in the shadow of English usage, generalizing over time from taste to experience on a similar track as *relish* and *zest*.

### Was There a Single Moment When Gusto Changed?

Probably not. In most cases it is difficult to trace words to a single influential usage. (Not all words are invented or adapted by a Chaucer, a Shakespeare, or a King James Bible.) Rather, *gusto* most likely crept into the usage denoted "[very common from the beginning of the 19th cent](https://oed.com/view/Entry/82701)" in the OED:

> 2. Keen relish or enjoyment displayed in speech or action; zest.

For instance, note the gap between these four quotes in the OED:

> 1693   W. Congreve Old Batchelour i. i. 3   It adds a **Gusto** to an Amour.
>
> 1727   A. Hamilton New Acct. E. Indies I. p. xiv   The Taste of those Times relished all he presented with a very good **Gusto**.
>
> 1808   W. Scott Let. 19 Nov. (1932) II. 131   We have been both dining and supping upon them [sc. herrings] with great **gusto**.
>
> 1866   ‘G. Eliot’ Felix Holt II. xxxi. 258   The second Tory joke was performed with much **gusto**.

So in 58 years the examples jump from *gusto* relating to food (herrings? OK) to comedic performance. Yet we also have examples of *gusto* referring to love in William Congreve, and that's over a century before Scott or Eliot. So even if we restricted ourselves to looking at popular writing from the late 18th century to mid 19th century for some single usage that explains why *gusto* changed, that's a lot of time and a lot of texts to look through.

Even if we restrict ourselves to a single genre of influence, like *opera*, we will find results in a database like Eighteenth Century Collections Online pointing to operas in print. However, we will also find references to other Italian literature, like the epic romance *Orlando Furioso* by Ariosto:

> L'aver avuto in poesia buon **gusto**,
>
> La proscrizione iniqua gli perdona.
>
> (But [Augustus's] good **taste** in poetry compensates for the evil of his proscriptions) (*OF* Canto 35, stanza 26, found on [Google Books](https://books.google.com/books?id=ls0MAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA286&lpg=PA286&dq=%22l%27aver%20avuto%20in%20poesia%20buon%20gusto%22&source=bl&ots=gt4IZllKUa&sig=ACfU3U1HWGkLuYMnoR_ZvM-WMYKQVEaflQ&hl=en&ppis=_c&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi2z_Ge8oDlAhVhUN8KHT9OAwwQ6AEwAnoECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22l'aver%20avuto%20in%20poesia%20buon%20gusto%22&f=false) in an 1826 edition)

In the search results on ECCO I also see results for Torquato Tasso (another widely-read author, esp. of *Gerusalemme Liberata*), a life of Lorenzo de' Medici by William Rosco, writings from travelers like Robert Southey ([who is writing about Spain and Portugal](https://catalog.hathitrust.org/Record/001858238)), and so on. A negative cannot definitively be proven, but the non-uniqueness of source thwarts an easy explanation of why *gusto* became popular.

Comment: Great answer. I note that _gusto_ appears figuratively in the "enthusiasm" sense at least as early as 1825: "thousands will swallow his impeachment with gusto, who have no relish for his vindication" (_Hobart [Tasmania] Town Gazette and Van Dieman's Land Advertiser_, January 14, 1825); "and describe them [the features of the surrounding country] himself not only with gusto, but with positive confidence in the reality and truth of his terms" (_Launceston [Tasmania] Advertiser_, August 27, 1835); "The General then read the letter with gusto" (_Richmond [Virginia] Advertiser_, April 11, 1839).